# I dual booted ubuntu 14.04 alongside side win7, both 64bit, theres no boot menu

Tags: dual-boot

So last night I decided to take the plunge and try Linux for the first time, so I found a tutorial to dual boot ubuntu 14.04, alongside win7, I created a live usb, shrank my computers (its a homebuilt)  HDD to free up space, then ran the ubuntu installer, selected the unallocated space partition for the install, didn't worry about a swap partition because I have 6gb of RAM, everything seemed to install correctly, computer restarted, and booted straight to ubuntu, restarted, same thing, no boot menu or anything, just straight to ubuntu, I even changed the boot priority in BIOS around, still only goes straight to ubuntu. how can I get the boot menu on startup? or even get windows to boot some other way? 
sorry for the long winded n00b question.

Comment: Straight after bios press and hold shift down. Does that open any options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot into Ubuntu - open a terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and execute :

```
sudo update-grub
```

This command will scan for bootable operating systems and add them to the GRUB boot menu.

Comment: oh my God, THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! everything works perfectly now! you get all the points!

Answer (score 0):

You could always give the tried-and-true program boot-repair a try. This will completely reinstall GRUB2 (the bootloader Linux uses to decide which OS to boot into), searching for and automatically adding all OSes it can find in the process.
To install it, follow the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
Summarized:
Open a terminal (ctrl+alt+t)
Run the following commands:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

Select "Recommended repair" and follow the prompts (spay special attention to the top of the window. It may occasionally show terminal commands for you to run. I used to always miss these) and reboot.
Good luck!